# Extract digit from unicode string - PHP RegExpression

Tags: php, codeigniter, preg-replace, codeigniter-2

I am Parsing a web page for getting the web page prize. the prize include a Rupee symbol (₹).

So i used preg_replace to extract digits.

For example:

```
$str='₹ 1,195 ';
echo preg_replace("/[^0-9]/", '', $str);
```

Output is :

```
2091195
```

I tried same code to execute on http://writecodeonline.com/php/.

There i m getting correct output `1195`.

I'm not getting what is the problem.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: If i'm executing your Answer it is showing the correct output. but it I'm loading it dynamically that time it is showing 209 before number

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the unicode string is UTF-8, you can use [the **u** (PCRE_UTF8) modifier<sup>*Docs*</sup>](http://php.net/manual/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php) to tell [`preg_replace`](http://php.net/preg_replace) that it should use UTF-8 mode. If not, re-encode it to UTF-8 first and then use the modifier.

Example ([Demo](http://codepad.viper-7.com/jzh8P6)):

```
$subject = '₹ 1,195 ';
$pattern = "/[^0-9]/u";
$result  = preg_replace($pattern, '', $subject);

echo $result;
```